# Can't stop audioRecorder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here's part of the code:

class AudioRecorderController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

```
var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?

func audioRecordingPath() -> NSURL {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager()

    let documentsFolderUrl = fileManager.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false, error: nil)

    return documentsFolderUrl!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Recording.m4a")

}


func audioRecordingSettings() -> NSDictionary {...}

func startRecordingAudio() {

    var error: NSError?

    let audioRecordingURL = self.audioRecordingPath()

    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioRecordingURL, settings: audioRecordingSettings() as [NSObject: AnyObject], error: &error)

    if let recorder = audioRecorder {

        recorder.delegate = self

        if recorder.prepareToRecord() && recorder.record() {

            println("Capture Succeed!")

            let delayInSeconds = 5.0
            let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                [weak self] in
                self!.audioRecorder!.stop()
                //It breaks here. 
                })

        } 
    }
}
```

It printed "Capture succeed" in the console, then crashed with error "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". 
What's the problem with the last line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

`self!.audioRecorder!.stop()`

with using the unwrapped constant

`recorder.stop()`